# How to setup MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have this app:
[github app](https://github.com/netguru/testblog#netguru-ror-workshop---test-blog)
 and this is what i get when I try to run it.

```
Could not connect to a primary node for replica set <Moped::Cluster nodes=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This means that MongoDB is either not setup properly or simply not running.

You can start up mongo by doing something like the following:

```
sudo mongod --fork --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb  --logpath /var/lib/log/mongodb.log --logappend
```

After that your ODM (Mongoid or the like) should be able to create the database.